# How to build a cascading dropdown inside a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf

I am Building a WPF form in which I want to achieve a cascading dropdown inside an ItemsControl. There would be multiple rows and Dropdown2 source is dependent on Dropdown1.
The row gets added when i add an item to FilterData, and the dropdown also populates, but i am not sure how to make a relational database with multiple rows

Here is what I have tried so far

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Filter" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterData}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Group}"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCondition" ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding ConditionList}" Width="80" Height="23" />
                        <ComboBox  x:Name="cmbType" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding TypeList}" Width="80" Height="23" />
                        <ComboBox  x:Name="cmbOperator" ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding OperatorList}" Width="80" Height="23" />


                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>


  public ObservableCollection<FilterData> _FilterData { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ConditionList> _ConditionList { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<TypeList> _TypeList { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<FilterData> FilterData
        {
            get { return _FilterData; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ConditionList> ConditionList
        {
            get { return _ConditionList; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<TypeList> TypeList
        {
            get { return _TypeList; }
        }

//Form Load event
 Filter.DataContext = this;
            AddRow();

private void AddRow()
        {
            _ConditionList = new ObservableCollection<ConditionList>()
            {
                new ConditionList() { Name = "AND" },
                new ConditionList() { Name = "OR" }
            };

            _FilterData.Add(new FilterData
            {
                Group = true,
            //    Condition = _ConditionList
            });


        }

// Modal

public class TypeList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConditionList
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilterData
    {
        public bool Group { get; set; }
        public ConditionList Condition { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you bind the `SelectedItem` and `ItemsSource` to the same source property? This makes no sense.

Comment: yeah, this code might be glitchy, I am new to MVVP and WPF. I don't know how to get ComboBox selected item in the backend

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the `SelectedItem` property of the first `ComboBox` to a source property of type `ConditionList`, you could populate the source collection for the second `ComboBox` (`TypeList`) in the setter of this one.

Make sure that you implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the source collection property that is being set to a new value, e.g.:

```
private ConditionList _selectedCondition;
public ConditionList SelectedCondition
{
    get { return _selectedCondition; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCondition = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        //populate the list...
        TypeList = new List<TypeList> { ... };
    }
}

public IEnumerable<TypeList> TypeList
{
    get { return _TypeList; }
    private set { _TypeList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCondition" ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCondition, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Width="80" Height="23" />

<ComboBox  x:Name="cmbType" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" ... />
```

Comment: Hi mm8, sorry, i am new to WPF and not getting where to add this code, When i add i am getting the below error
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<XLBytes.TypeList>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<XLBytes.TypeList>'.

Comment: There is no `ObservableCollection` present in my code sample so where are you getting this...?

Comment: Another problem i see is i am not getting the ComboBox selected value in FilterData object, it is always null

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Don't ask several things.

Comment: Sure, for the first question, I had _TypeList defined as ObservableCollection, do you want me to delete that?